# Dealing with embedded data in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Suppose I have a graph (tree, whatever) and the structure in plain JS is like:

```
var trees = [{
  name : 'my tree',
  nodes : [
    {
      id : 0,
      name : 'node 0',
      type : 'fruit',
      connectedTo : [1,2]
    },{
      id : 1,
      name : 'node 1',
      type : 'fruit',
      connectedTo : [3,4]
    },{
      id : 2,
      name : 'node 2',
      type : 'fruit',
      connectedTo : []
    },{
      id : 3,
      name : 'node 3',
      type : 'non-fruit',
      connectedTo : []
    },{
      id : 4,
      name : 'node 4',
      type : 'non-fruit',
      connectedTo : []
    }
  ]
}]
```

Now in Ember, it would require me to have a `Tree`, `Node` and maybe a type model. No biggie. However, I need the data to be parsed for a tree graph. But when I access the data, it's like a chain of `get()` and `then()` calls (relationships are async between models).

```
this.get('nodes').then(function(nodes){
  nodes.forEach(function(node){
    node.get('type').then(function(type){
      console.log(type.get('type')) // OMG
    });
  })
});
```

I was hoping to access them in dot-notation, something like `tree.nodes[1].type`. Is that possible in Ember? I have read several posts dealing with embedded data, and all they do is normalize external data to Ember models. I don't want that. What I want is to deal with embedded data *inside* the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use plainJS objects in Ember without the need to use Ember Data as in this [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/selek/1/edit).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{model.name}}
    {{#each item in model.nodes}}
      <li>{{item.id}}</li>
      {{#each connectedTo in item.connectedTo}}
        {{connectedTo}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Once, you set your model data to your controller content, you could operate with your content as normal ember objects.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    changeValues: function(){

      this.controller.set('content.name', 'changed');
      this.controller.set('content.nodes.firstObject.id', 7);


    }
  },
  model: function() {
    return {
  name : 'my tree',
  nodes : [
    {
      id : 0,
      name : 'node 0',
      type : 'fruit',
      connectedTo : [1,2]
    },{
      id : 1,
      name : 'node 1',
      type : 'fruit',
      connectedTo : [3,4]
    },{
      id : 2,
      name : 'node 2',
      type : 'fruit',
      connectedTo : []
    },{
      id : 3,
      name : 'node 3',
      type : 'non-fruit',
      connectedTo : []
    },{
      id : 4,
      name : 'node 4',
      type : 'non-fruit',
      connectedTo : []
    }
  ]
};

  }
});
```

Comment: I notice `firstObject`. Is there a way to set it to an arbitrary value?

Comment: That's an odd notation. Found out that I can still access them natively, and just use `get` and `set` to trigger observers. This was a big help though, never knew this was possible. Thanks again!:D